# How to animate an image along an arc

Tags: jquery, animation, jquery-animate

I want to animate am image along the path of an arc. This arc is a 45o segment of the circumference of a circle.

I understand that previously the easiest way to do this was to use https://github.com/weepy/jquery.path, however this code appears to be defunct (demo no longer works in Chrome).

How would I otherwise approach doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `step` callback in the animation to make your own custom effect. Animate some property that doesn't have a visible effect, and set the coordinates from that:

```
$('div').css({ fontSize: 0 }).animate({
    fontSize: 45
},{
    duration: 2000,
    easing: "swing",
    step: function(t, fx){
        var a = t / 57.296; // from degrees to radians
        var x = 100 + Math.cos(a) * 50;
        var y = 100 + Math.sin(a) * 50;
        $(this).css({ left: x, top: y });
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/a9eXE/

Comment: Thanks, how would I set the degrees or circle radius in this?

Comment: @alias51: The example loops from 0 degrees to 45 degrees, and the radius is 50. The center of the circle is as 100,100.

Comment: Great, thanks. Is there any what to make this smoother? In my browser (Chrome 30) it is a little jerky.

Comment: @alias51: Not that I know of, the browser rounds the coordinates to the closest pixel which makes the path a bit jaggedy. If you look at one of the slower elements in the jQuery.path demo, you see that they actually doesn't move smoothly, but there are so many elements moving around that you don't see it unless you look for it.

Comment: @Guffa There is a way to smooth it out: easing. If you use the default easing in jQuery, you may not always get the best result. If you also use jQuery UI, you get a lot more options that provide better animations.

All I changed in the fiddle was adding jQuery UI and a certain easing and it's very smooth: http://jsfiddle.net/6mn7Loms/

It looks even better if it's sped up to 1000ms

Comment: @SamiFouad: It only looks smoother because it's moving faster. When the element is moving several pixels each frame, the pixel rounding isn't noticable.

Comment: @Guffa My friend, easing matters. A lot. Speed is certainly a factor in determining the smoothness, but both animations side by side at a relatively slow speed (2.5 seconds) shows two very different results for smoothness. The jQuery UI easing is smoother. here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c3vpjnp3/